# How can I change the TargetControlID of AutoCompleteExtender client side (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, autocompleteextender

Normally, I can can set the TargetControlID server side using something like this:

```
    AutoCompleteExtender ace = new AutoCompleteExtender();
    ace.ID = "AutoCompleteExtender1";
    ace.TargetControlID = "whatever";
```

I know how to grab the AutoCompleteExtender client side, but I am looking for a method to update the TargetControlID client side too. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it's not even possible?? http://forums.asp.net/t/1242007.aspx/1

Comment: See if jQuery Autocomplete helps: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: I like the suggestion for the future (jQuery autocomplete). I will probably switch over in the future. But I'm on a project deadline so I can't switch midstream :)

Comment: Taking that TargetControlID cannot be changed, wondering about the scenario why you want to change it on client-side?

Comment: Good question. I thought it would be an easy way to load up all of the elements service methods, but now that I realize it isn't possible, I added a function server side to do it.

Comment: The only way you can change TargetControlID is updatepanel wrap the control in update panel and make an async call to server that should do it.

Comment: It's stuff like this that made me give up on the AJAX control toolkit. If you want to do anything even slightly out of the ordinary, you're gonna have a bad time. I swapped it out for just using JQuery and Page Methods and never looked back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Microsoft didn't think was important, so there is not a way to do this at this time :)

Answer (score 2):

Well sadly this is not possible for existing instance of AutoCompleteExtender. There are a few methods that you might be interested in like below

```
var x = $find("AutocompleteBehaviorID");//find the instance

x.get_completionListElementID();//get the ID of target textbox

x.set_completionListElementID();//set the ID of target textbox has no effect though :(

x._completionListElement();//direct access to DOM element that acts as target
```

the problem here seems initialized version attaches additional events to target textbox during `init` phase of the control toolkit( yeah client side too has a `init` phase). When a initialized version is made to change as the target (as you wanted to do) then these events `keypress`,`blur` etc are not added hence you don't see any changes. But if you knew javascript you can do the below to make it work with any textbox.

`$create(Behavior,{properties},{events},interfaces,target);`

where

#### Behavior

`AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteBehavior`

#### properties

is a javascript object as below (there are more properties but these suffice

```
{
    "completionInterval": 1,
    "completionListElementID": "empty panel id",
    "completionListItemCssClass": "css class name",
    "delimiterCharacters": ";",
    "highlightedItemCssClass": "css class name",
    "id": "CLIENTSIDEID",
    "minimumPrefixLength": 1,
    "serviceMethod": "WebMethodName",
    "servicePath": "AbsolutePath to asmx file"
}
```

#### Events

there are more events available

```
{
    "itemSelected": jsFn,
    "populated": jsFn
}
```

#### The Target

Target element is the most important. It is this text box that all the events ,bells and whistles attracted to.

`$get("ELEMENT ID")`

now that is all over , you can initialize a instance of auto complete though javascript all the time. Just make sure the ID already does not exist.

Comment: Apparently AjaxControlToolkit is now Sys.Extended.UI, so $create(AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteBehavior, ..., ..., ..., ...); would be $create(Sys.Extended.UI.AutoCompleteBehavior, ..., ..., ..., ...);